# Variable equivalent of b'some string' in python

Tags: python, python-3.x, byte

what is the best equivalent way to do `b'some string'` but with a string variable? I've tried `b(somevar)` but that doesn't work. I saw some to byte array functions but I'm not sure if that's over complicating it as for literal strings a simple `b` placed in front of the string is enough.

The end goal, before I'm down voted to no end lol, is to use strings for telnet connections. For simple writes I can do `b'ehlo a.com'` as an example. But if I have say `'ehlo a.com'` stored as a string var, how can I use that?

**Code:**

```
writestring = 'RCPT TO: postmaster@'+domains[domain]
bytesdata = writestring.encode('ascii')
tn.write(writestring)
```

**Error:**

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Python34\lib\tkinter\__init__.py", line 1487, in __call__
    return self.func(*args)
  File "C:\Users\kylec\Desktop\DataMotion\Python\MailChecker.py", line 108, in checkMail
    tn.write(writestring)
  File "C:\Python34\lib\telnetlib.py", line 289, in write
    if IAC in buffer:
TypeError: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes
```

Comment: You mean you want to *encode* some Unicode string?

Comment: I'm trying to use strings for telnet connections. For simple writes I can  do b'ehlo a.com' as an example. But if I have say ehlo a.com stored as a string var, how can I use that?

Comment: See [Pragmatic Unicode, or, How do I stop the pain?](http://nedbatchelder.com/text/unipain.html)

Comment: Why can't you just write the string to the connection?

Comment: Doesn't `conn.write(stringvar)` work?

Comment: @Barmar Hopefully not, because that would mean something is silently doing the encoding for you, which was abolished for stdlib code in 3.x for good.

Comment: Everything I read about telnet says it has to be byte encoded first, hence the b'literal strings'

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `b'..'` literal notation is just one way to create a `bytes` object, just as using a regular string literal creates a `str` object. `bytes` hold binary data, while `str` holds *text* data as Unicode codepoints.

If you are trying to create a `bytes` object from a text (unicode) string, you need to *encode* your Unicode data with some codec. What codec exactly, depends on what you need to use the binary data *for*.

```
bytesdata = unicodestring.encode('utf-8')
```

would encode the text to UTF-8 bytes, for example.

`EHLO` is a [RFC 2821 SMTP command](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821), which [uses ASCII codepoints only](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc2821#section-4.1.1.1), so you can just encode to `ASCII` here:

```
unicodestring.encode('ascii')
```

From the [relevant source code](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/telnetlib.py#l282) from your traceback, you can see that a `bytes` value is expected ([`IAC` is a `bytes` value](http://hg.python.org/cpython/file/3.4/Lib/telnetlib.py#l52)).

Comment: I'm trying to use strings for telnet connections. For simple writes I can do b'ehlo a.com' as an example. But if I have say ehlo a.com stored as a string var, how can I use that?

Comment: @Kyle: The telnet standard uses ASCII commands exclusively, so encode to ASCII.

Comment: I've updated my question to include more information.

Comment: @Kyle No need to repost your question 3 times :p

Comment: Alright I gave this a shot and I'm getting this error: 'in <string>' requires string as left operand, not bytes, when trying to do a tn.write().

Comment: Than what was the purpose of the b'literal string' doesn't that convert it to bytes? All my plain literal string tn.write() methods work fine. Just not when working with variables.

Comment: @Kyle: that *produces* a `bytes` object, it doesn't convert anything. Conversion is done by encoding a Unicode string. But your *exception* tells us that `tn.write()` expects to get a `str`, not a `bytes`.

Comment: Ok so the encoding is not needed then? If I don't encode it I get the same error.

Comment: @Kyle: Yes, the `encode` is needed. Your traceback, as posted, indicates you didn't send a bytes value but a unicode value.

Comment: So it should be a utf-8?

Comment: @Kyle: It should by a **`bytes` object**. How you encoded that object doesn't matter to `telnetlib`. Out of interest, why are you not using the [`smtplib` module](https://docs.python.org/3/library/smtplib.html) instead?

Comment: The scope of this project is to use it through telnet otherwise I would as it looks much easier. Alright what's the best way to go string to bytes object then if I can't use the 'b'?

Comment: Right, I tried this: bytesdata = str.encode(writestring) but got the same error.